# How to disable Direct3D Acceleration on Windows 7?

Tags: directx, direct3d, hardware-acceleration

I have tried to disable 3D acceleration on my machine that operation system is Windows 7. 
I opened the DirectX Diagnostic Tool but DirectX Features can not be changed:

[image]

In addition I also tried to change Troubleshoot settings. However, it also can't be changed:

[image]

How can i disable directX featrues?

Note: My directX version is 11.

Comment: Why do you want to deactivate 3D acceleration? There is a similar question for Windows 8 on superuser : http://superuser.com/questions/495303/how-do-i-disable-directdraw-and-direct3d-acceleration-on-windows-8. Maybe it works for your, too.

Comment: I need it for an application. I should disable 3D Acceleration on Windows 7..

Answer (score 1):

If you mean for your own application, you can disable GPU hardware acceleration by opting for the WARP driver type (`D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP`) when creating the Direct3D device (`D3D11CreateDevice`).

If you mean for an existing application, you can do the same with the DirectX Control Panel (`dxcpl.exe`) and selecting "Force WARP".

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable Aero(Mostly not necessary but do it for now) Disable aero
2. Download directx 9.0c control panel from here
   http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/microsoft_directx_control_panel.html
3. Extract and run "directx.cpl" as administrator.
4. Goto Direct3D and DirectDraw tabs and uncheck "Allow hardware acceleration ".